# Can Smart DNS Cause Geo-locked Data to be Streamed Directly from the Web Site to the PC?

Tags: dns, smart

On another forum I am having a discussion with someone who claims that a Smart DNS Proxy Server is similar to a VPS SNI Proxy Server with a VPS DNS Server where only streaming media that is not geo-locked will be streamed directly to the PC and if the data is geo-locked, it will stream through the proxy server. He believes that since the streaming media on the BBC iPlayer is geo-locked, Smart DNS will always stream the data through the proxy server.

On the other hand, I believe that all data, whether geo-locked or not, is streamed directly to the PC and only the authentication stage data is required to go through the proxy server.

**Who is correct?**

If I am correct, my theory is that the way it is accomplished is that upon completion of the authentication stage, the Smart DNS server has the ability to create an authentication token with the user's IP address on the video web sever so that when the Smart DNS Proxy Server is disconnected from the user, the user will remain authenticated and can therefore stream geo-locked data. Does this part make any sense? If not, how is the user's IP Address authenticated so that geo-locked data will be transferred to the user?